# Matplotlib in Tkinter segmentation fault on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu, tkinter, segmentation-fault

I'm using matplotlib inside a tkinter window on python3. The program works fine on my coding machine (ubuntu18.04 running in windows WSL). Unfortunately, I need this program to run on my Raspberry Pi 4 which has Ubuntu20.04 64bit installed with the distro Ubuntu Mate 1.24.0.
When I run my program on the RPi I get segmentation fault as soon as I call

```
FigureCanvasTkAgg.draw()
```

Nevertheless, I use matplotlib in other programs (using pyplot) and they work fine.

Details:

- these are my imports:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

- This is a brief summary of what my program does:

  - I have a class that implements the tkinter window; in the constructor, I instantiate the following plot variables:

```
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.subplot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(
            self.figure, master=self.tkWindow)
```

- Then, the class has this method to update the plot:

```
    def updatePlot(self, x, y, title, xlabel, ylabel):
        self.subplot.clear()
        self.subplot.set_title(title)
        self.subplot.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        self.subplot.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        self.subplot.plot(x, y, color='red', label='unfiltered')
        self.subplot.legend(loc='upper right')
        self.canvas.draw() # <- this is the line that causes the crash
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, columnspan=5)
```

- Versions on my windows machine:

  - Ubuntu 18.04.5
  - Python3 3.6.9
  - Matplotlib 2.1.1
  - Tkinter 0.1.0
- Versions on my RPi:

  - Ubuntu 20.04.3
  - Python3 3.8.10
  - Matplotlib 3.3.4
  - Tkinter 0.1.0

Comment: Can you please show us all of the segmentation fault output? Also please post a [mre].

Comment: For sure, sorry if I didn't include it in the first place. I'm working on it.

Comment: Update: I wrote an example that should be identical to my code: the example works, and I can not see where it differs from my original program. Anyway, Clown Down's solution works, so I'll go with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian running on it.

Try changing `FigureCanvasTkAgg.draw()` with `FigureCanvasTkAgg.draw_idle()`

Comment: Thank you, this works! Btw, any idea on why?

Comment: @LucioPhys Actually `FigureCanvasTkAgg` doesn't implement the `draw_idle` method. Also I found that `.draw_idle` is the same as `<FigureCanvasTkAgg>._tkcanvas.after_idle(<FigureCanvasTkAgg>.draw)`. For the source code look [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7b9e1ce18fd2d1e26c19bd1f14dec4822de40d59/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py#L244).